# Is it permissible for a Muslim to praise another God as a courtesy during a Christian wedding?

Tags: non-muslim, christianity, celebration, wedding

I know some Muslims who have been invited to one of their evangelical Christian friend's weddings, and there will surely be a lot of singing and worshipping of Jesus Christ as lord and savior.  Is it acceptable for a Muslim to attend such a wedding ceremony, and is it acceptable to sing songs that go against the teachings of Islam as a courtesy to Christian friends (or, for that matter, friends of other religions)?

Comment: From a Christian perspective, no Christian doctrine would want you to sing worship songs as a courtesy if you don't believe them. It would be more respectful to attend the wedding. Listening to the worship songs without singing them yourself would generally be considered the polite thing to do. If questioned you can simply say something like "I chose not to participate in that way because I don't believe the same things you do, but thanks for letting me watch." On the other hand singing or doing other ceremonial things with an unbelieving heart could be considered offensive.

Comment: Muslims can't live in isolation. We have to tolerate to a certain degree. Check this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7waux4ESD0

Answer (score 2):

There is no objection in Islamic Sharia for a Muslim to accept the invitation of a Christian to attend a wedding ceremony in the church provided there are no Munkarat (all evil acts and things) such as: drinking alcohol, singing, statues and performing forms of worship that are not for Allah. If such evil acts or things are present in the church then, it becomes unlawful to go there. Abdel Razak reported from Aslam (the servant of Umar ) who said: 'When Umar (Radiya Allahu Anhu) came to Al Sham, a top ranking Christian man made some food for him. He said to him: 'I would like you to do me a favor to visit me and eat with me'. Umar (Radiya Allahu Anhu) replied: 'We do not enter your churches because of the pictures in them' .

Comment: Well, it would obviously vary by church / etc, but taking those in order: alcohol: if the wedding includes "communion", then others may be taking a small quantity of communion wine (it would absolutely **not** be expected (or accepted) for a non-Christian guest to participate, but they would normally stay and observe), singing / statues / worship other than Allah: hard to know in advance, but there could be songs / devotions towards Mary, Jesus, Christian saints, etc, and statues are not uncommon in churches (Catholic churches may have a large and graphic crucifix). Added for context.

Comment: Of course, as a corollary of the above, a wedding is not always the same as another event in the church; for example, there might not be communion. It may be advisable to enquire what the logistics will be. Christianity has more more variety than Islam, and neighbouring congregations can be *radically* different in style (at the extremes; Greek Orthodox right through to Christian Anarchist)

Comment: Please provide a source or citation for the first part of the answer, and a reference to the collection the athaar of 'Umar you quote. Thank you, and welcome to Islam.SE!

Comment: The fatwa is on this website: http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=84946# it makes sense to not go anywhere where there is evil i.e. free mixing, alcohol, etc.

Comment: Very interesting video by Shiekh Khalid Yasin discussing this issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7waux4ESD0